# How to prevent SVG arrow from being override

Tags: css, svg

I made this simple SVG animation **[HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/wyfegz1t/2/)** , The code for drawing the dashed lines is below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var offset = parseInt($('#move-opacity').attr("offset"));
    setInterval(function() {
      $('#move-opacity').attr("offset", offset + "%");
      if (offset < 100) {
        $('#last-opacity').attr("offset", (offset + 1) + "%");
      }
      offset++;

    }, 25);

    /* code for secound line animation */
    var offset1 = parseInt($('#move-opacity-1').attr('offset'));
    setInterval(function() {
      $('#move-opacity-1').attr("offset", offset + "%");
      if (offset < 100) {
        $('#last-opacity-1').attr("offset", (offset + 1) + "%");
      }
      offset++;

    }, 25);


    $("#lock").attr( "class" , "animated bounceInUp");
    $("#quote-icon").attr( "class" , "animated bounceInUp delay-05s");


    $("#lock").addClass("animated bounceInUp");

});
```

Now if you notice clearly even the arrow is overridden with a dashed arrow , once the line is drawn , how to prevent this from happening ?

Comment: @MichaelMullany who are you to decide whats minimal and whats not ?? .. its minimal already , i took of a few plugins already off to make the code minimal , one of them being waypoints ,because i wanted the animation only when the scroll reached a certain point. I am mindful of the fact that problems on SO need to be isolated to fit the needs of a larger audiance.

Comment: I don't think this a case of opinion, or of who I think I am to decide. A minimal test case is straightforward: it's the minimum amount of content/code that still demonstrates the problem. A good SO code problem strips away all the extraneous content and code so people don't have to parse through extraneous classes and content just to find the problematic content. I've often solved my own problems before I even ask a question by isolating problematic code through this process. As you can see, the problem wasn't even in your JavaScript.

Comment: @MichaelMullany let me put it this way , i am new to svg , and know very little about it , so its very likely that i would get an error and not the desired result , and then it would take me quite a few hours or even a day to get that error solved .. no matter how trivial the error or bug is , now instead if i were to ask a person who actually knew about SVG's and has worked with them for a while , it would probably take them a few minutes to figure out the solution and give me the answer (eg. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34013470/how-to-draw-animation-from-end-of-the-line-svg )

Comment: continuing ...... in the above question i knew that something needs to be just "inverted" , but did't know what exactly , as you see in the end the solution turns out to be something that exactly what i taught , yet i'am pretty sure even if i had sat on it a few hours , i'd probably not come up with the solution. My point is as a developer you should realise when you quest to find a solution is leading you down the path of "unproductivity"  .

Comment: continuing .... as proof please go through some of the questions that i've posted on SO and then in another tab open up some of the questions that get posted which you'll find in the "newest" questions tab , u'll notice a considerable difference in quality. lastly and most importantly , the questions i have asked take a "beginner" level of understanding of SVG's not even something intermediate or advance , hence , i don't need't to go into every detail and micro-isolate my problem.

Comment: about your statement "As you can see, the problem wasn't even in your JavaScript."  ... have you noticed on SO you need to add code every time you add a fiddle. good feature you think ? , maybe , but in my situation , i just had to post some code as a hack to work around this , i obviously could''t post the big chunk of SVG code.

Comment: Fair enough Alexander

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual problem is because the `polygon` that produces the arrow head already has `class='st0'` which produces a yellow colored fill and the below code is also adding a yellow colored gradient as a `stroke` to the arrow head and thus you are ending up seeing both.

```
#dotted-lines-1 {
    stroke: url(#yellow-gradient);
    fill: none;
    stroke-width:3;
    stroke-miterlimit: 10;
    stroke-dasharray:4.8732,2.9239;
}
#dotted-lines-2 {
    stroke: url(#yellow-gradient);
    fill: none !important;
    stroke-width:3;
    stroke-miterlimit: 10;
    stroke-dasharray:4.8732,2.9239;
}
```

To overcome the issue, apply the yellow gradient only to the `line` and `path` elements within the `g` like in the below code block.

```
#dotted-lines-1 line, #dotted-lines-1 path {
    stroke: url(#yellow-gradient);
    fill: none;
    stroke-width:3;
    stroke-miterlimit: 10;
    stroke-dasharray:4.8732,2.9239;
}
#dotted-lines-2 line, #dotted-lines-2 path {
    stroke: url(#yellow-gradient);
    fill: none !important;
    stroke-width:3;
    stroke-miterlimit: 10;
    stroke-dasharray:4.8732,2.9239;
}
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/wyfegz1t/4/)